# How to react on a button click in a Templated Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written a custom Templated Control which contains a button:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="local:IncrementalFlipView">
    <Border
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="^" x:Name="PreviousPageButton" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <TextBlock Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0" FontSize="16" />
            <Button Content="v" x:Name="NextPageButton"/>
        </StackPanel>

    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

My problem is, that I don't know how to react on the button's click event. I implemented a `Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)` eventhandler in my Template Control's code but it does not catch the button's click event.

```
public sealed class IncrementalFlipView : Control
{
    public IncrementalFlipView()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(IncrementalFlipView);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!");
    }
}
```

Any idea how to react on that clicked event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way (my point of view) would be to use `Command Bindings`. 
Your styled button in your Templated control will look something like this:

```
 <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.BackCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type YourUIType}}}"                                      CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

The type of your `AncestorType` depends on the UI element that you are using.

In your main Window you should define the `Command`:

```
private RelayCommand _backCommand;
public ICommand BackCommand
{
    get { return _backCommand ?? (_backCommand = new RelayCommand(Back)); }
}
```

If you go through the Internet you will see the basic `RelayCommand` definition for the `ICommand` interface (see [here]).[1](http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.com.es/2013/04/icommand-interface-and-relaycommand.html)

And then, you only have to define the `Back` method (it has a paramethrized object):

```
private void Back(object obj)
{
    // Go back command
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah okay, I solved it by myself. It is not possible to pass the Clicked event to the base class. But one can access the button when the template is loaded and let him subscribe the clicked event like this:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    Button PreviousPageButton = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PreviousPageButton");
    PreviousPageButton.Click += PreviousPageButton_Click;
}
```

Comment: I think you should use `Command bindingd` to do so better than auto-suscribe to an event.